# cleartool protect -chmod 770 <vob-tag-name> ERROR

Tags: chmod, cleartool

This command does not work:

```
cleartool protect -chmod 770 <vob-tag-name>
```

I get the following error:

```
cleartool> protect -chmod 770 vob-tag-name

cleartool: Error: Unable to access "vob-tag-name": ClearCase object not found.
```

The VOB tag is valid and points to the correct VOB location.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permission levels to change these attributes on the VOB location?

Answer (score 1):

In above command, you should be using path like `protect -chmod 770 /vobs/vobname/dir/file.txt`

To protect the VOB you should use the protectvob command.

Answer (score 0):

Protect changes permissions/ownership of a VOB objects (element(file/directory/..), meta type (branch/...),).

```
 eg: For a file --> **ct protect –chmod 770 main.pl** , 
     for all elements in the directories --> **ct protect –recurse –chmod 770 src**
```

Answer (score 0):

run `ct setview <view-name>`
then cd to the VOB `cd <vob-tag>`
Then run `/usr/atria/bin/cleartool protect -chmod 770 -recurse <vob-tag>`